# Settings does not open for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: gnome, package-management, 20.04, dependencies, settings

I've just updated my ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04 but some packages appear to have been removed. As a result I cannot open my settings through GUI or the Command line. It gives me instances of problem packages but i somehow can't resolve those too. There seems to be some problem with the libpython3.8-stdlib but i don't exactly know what. I tried opening the settings using `gnome-control-center` but says `The following packages have unmet dependencies: gnome-control-center : Depends: libsmbclient (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1) but it is not going to be installed`  As I try to find the problems with the respective libraries, I finally stop at `libpython3.8-stdlib` but I may be wrong.

I can't open settings because I think some packages might have been accidently deleted or become corrupted. How do I solve this?

Comment: Looks like you neglected to remove wrong-version or non-Ubuntu software before your release-upgrade. Resolving unmet dependencies can be quite tedious, but is not particularly difficult. Start by identifying and uninstalling the wrong-version software that is causing the unmet dependency. Hint: It's almost always from an unofficial source, like a PPA or non-Ubuntu repository.

Comment: I get what you are trying to say but how do I find the software that might be causing the problem...Do I only look at GUI softwares visible in my 'Show Applications' menu? And if so, how do I know if the software is not for this version?

Comment: That's the tedious part. You must learn how to do those tasks. You need to understand how apt sources work, and how to use the `apt cache policy` command. There is no magic incantation to fix it, because the system is doing exactly what you told it to do when you unwisely added the wrong-version software. If this learning is beyond the effort that you are willing to expend, then backup your data and clean-install 20.04...and next time be more wary about adding non-Ubuntu software or wrong-version software.

Comment: Say I do find the software with unmet dependencies and succesfully uninstall it (haven't yet)...what do I do next?

Comment: Then your system is fixed. apt will install the missing packages that it cannot currently install due to the version conflict..